# Bad CallLog Grouping after updating a Call Log on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, calllog

**INTRO:**

I am creating an application that redirects a call to another number and then tone dials the actual target number.
For example: every time I call a foreign number lets say "+46 123 4567" it actually redirects to a local number "+1 555 1234" and dials the foreign number as tones after a 2 sec. pause.

After the call I update the call log using CallLog.Calls so that the call log shows the actual target number (not the local proxy).

Everything works fine, My Nexus 5 and all emulators behave the way I want them to.

**PROBLEM:**

However on some Samsung devices (Specifically 4.2.2 Galaxy S2+ (GT-I905P)), a problem occurs:

If I place a call to lets say a UK contact and after that I place a call to SE (Sweden) contact both of these get grouped together in the Samsung call log. So instead of seeing two separate call logs:

[image]

I only see

[image]

As if I called the Swedish number twice, but that isn't true. It is obvious that somehow Samsung is still grouping the calls using the proxy number and ignoring CallLog.Calls when grouping calls.

When I check the output of CallLog.Calls all is like it should be:
(The last two lines of the CallLog.Calls when ordered by DATE Ascending:

id: 25261 name: Test Uk number: 00446342845 duration: 2 new: 1 date: 1409833561100

id: 25262 name: Test SE number: 004629564647 duration: 3 new: 1 date: 1409833582098

**HOW I UPDATE THE CALL LOGS:**

```
    // get Log ordered by date, so that the newest is the last entry:
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    cursor.moveToLast();

    // get a field unique value from the cursor so that I know which field to update:
    // (should probably use _ID instead of date)
    long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, destinationNumber); // update the number

    context.getContentResolver().update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, cv,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + " = ?"
           , new String[]{String.valueOf(date)});
```

So the question is:
**How does Samsung group these calls? And what can I do to counter this?**

Comment: You might consider posting your code showing how you are making your second entry in the `CallLog` `ContentProvider`, as that might provide some clues. But please bear in mind that how a dialer app renders its call log is up to its implementers, not you, and for pre-installed dialers, it might involve information not exposed through the `CallLog` `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @CommonsWare I've updated the question with code how I update the last call entry after a call.

Comment: OK, I'm confused. If you are updating an existing entry, how are you getting two of them, per your reported output? Are two entries going in there "naturally" (one for the original call, one for the redirect), and you're trying to update the latter?

Comment: @CommonsWare Both entries are updated the same - just after a phone call has been made. The problem is that even though I update them to different numbers they get grouped as one call as illustrated in the second picture above.

Comment: "Both entries are updated the same" -- then I am even more confused. You are getting two entries for some reason, and you are updating both of them to replace the phone number, yet the phone number is only changing on one of them?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am updating them one at a time, an entry gets updated after a phone call has been made. I've printed two of them to illustrate that CallLog.Calls infact has two different numbers but the dialer app groups them as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an advice from a colleague I've actually solved this issue by doing a **delete and insert** instead of an **update**. Now the Samsung dialer groups the calls right.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Samsung group these calls?

I would assume that Samsung's call log display is not being driven directly from the `CallLog`, at least in part. There is no particular requirement that a call log be based solely upon the `CallLog` provider's contents.

> And what can I do to counter this?

AFAIK, there is nothing you can do. Samsung's dialer app is Samsung's, and they can display whatever data they want, however they want.